# How to include smoke/fog/volume into mist pass

Tags: compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I'm using mist in this node for compositing
[image]
And have run into the problem that a smoke domain using a volume shader is rendered as white
[image]
Is there any way to fix that? Or maybe getting the same mist effect in other way that takes volumes into account?

Comment: 4 years old post https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/68346 there is a workaround that I didnt understand how can be useful, but probably for you ... honestly I don't know how to imagine the volumetric pass should looks like. Mist or depth pass represents pixels in space ... where should be positioned a pixel of volume? It is the same like if you use GeoNodes to convert volume to mesh. The result of such thing wouldn't be useful for compositing at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK so there is something you can do as workaround, but it requires some steps over (and probably impossible for complex scenes or shaders).

This scene is just Cube emitting smoke in box ...

[image]
[image]

The only one thing (at the moment) that came to my mind is to render it separately with gradient shader.

Here Normalised in Compositor
[image]
[image]

Node group (used in all shaders).
[image]

Solid objects
[image]

Normally you could use blender's feature "Material Overwrite", so just by one click you can render scene with a single material, but since smoke requires different material you have to assign them manually. Or render smoke as separate layer and compose it into depth.